# Mysql syntax error in ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

Sql keeps throwing me a syntax error and I can't seem to figure out whats wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE `productList` ALTER COLUMN `ASIN` VARCHAR(32);
```

The error is the normal sql syntax error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(32)' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ALTER TABLE `productList` MODIFY COLUMN `ASIN` VARCHAR(32);
```

The syntax to [change the column name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) is

> ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN new-column-definition

Comment: This was correct. Thanks, it was driving me crazy. All the answers online said I could use ALTER COLUMN. I'll mark this correct in 10 minutes.

Comment: @RyanWeinstein:- Added the manual link also . You can refer that as well!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MODIFY COLUMN instead of ALTER COLUMN if you want to change the column definition.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

It's modify, not alter column.

ALTER TABLE table_name
  MODIFY column_name column_definition
    [ FIRST | AFTER column_name ];